# What is the radius in newtons second law of motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

We have a rod in a vertical plane rotating about a smooth fixed hinge.

After we apply Newton's second law we can say that:
$$R_n-mg\cos\theta=ma_t$$
where $R_n$ is the normal reaction due to the hinge and $a_t$ is the acceleration in the tangential direction.

Now $a_t=\alpha r$ where $r$ is the radius, My question is what is $r$ a radius for?

My assumption was it should be the radius of the circle created by the rotation of the rod(Length of the rod). Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: It is length of rod $L$ in your diagram.

Comment: @NeilLibertine that was also what I thought of but apparently that's not the case read the answer below

Comment: @YoussefMohamed Yes, the translational force is acting on the centre of mass which is translated into rotational motion at pivot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Net force on an extended body relates to acceleration of the center of mass.  This follows from momentum of an extended body being mass times the velocity of the center of mass.  Net external force equals the derivative of momentum with respect to time.  If mass doesn't change, then we have mass times the first derivative of the velocity OF THE CENTER OF MASS.  By defining your acceleration to be tangential relative to the fixed pivot, then the radius must be measured from that particular pivot to the center of mass.

Note:  Some of the normal force at the pivot does contribute to radial acceleration.  If it did not, then the radial component of weight would pull the rod away from the pivot point.  To provide a radial centripetal acceleration toward the pivot, the radial component of $R_n$ must actually be larger than the radial component of the weight.